# Is there any way by which I can capture the wifi probe requests without using monitor mode?

Tags: networking, wifi, linux-networking, 802.1

For some reason, keeping the wifi interface in monitor mode on my machine is crashing it(its a raspberry pi, I'm assuming its crashing because of the amount of traffic being intercepted, but lets not get into that for now). My requirement is that I have to capture the 802.11 probe requests. Is there a way I can capture this without having my interface on monitor mode?

Comment: I do not think this is possible.

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is SDR Software Defined Radio. Depending on what you want to do this may be huge overhead, but decode the wifi signals as radio http://hackaday.com/?s=sdr

Comment: I'm looking to capture the probe request packet. its a 802.11 management frame

Comment: I'm assuming that there might be something(as in, for getting probe requests without having the put the interface on monitor mode) because, without that we would not have had the list of available networks and other such things. If Only I can somehow get the api's it accesses or something.